# How to send push via o:socket from EJB to Client?

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I need help for the cooperation between @EJB and @CDI

Hi all,

I would like to have the following scenario:
1) In my app a Notification is created (in database)
2) Afterwards a Push Notification should be send to the specific client
3) In Client it will update a specific @form from my page...

Here is my code:

```
@Stateless
public class NotificationCreationSendServiceBean implements NotificationCreationSendService {

@Inject
private BeanManager beanManager;

public void createNotification {

// createNotificationInDatabase();
.....

        PushEvent event = new PushEvent("Test");
        beanManager.fireEvent(event);
}
}
```

My JSF Bean:

```
import static org.omnifaces.util.Messages.addGlobalError;
import static org.omnifaces.util.Messages.addGlobalInfo;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class NotificationSocket implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private LoginBean loginBean;

    @Inject
    @Push(channel = "notificationChannel")
    private PushContext push;

    /**
     * Push Notification
     * 
     * @param recipientUser
     */
    public void pushUser(@Observes PushEvent event) {
        Set<Future<Void>> sent = push.send(event.getMessage(), loginBean.getCurrentEmployee().getId());

        if (sent.isEmpty()) {
            addGlobalError("This user does not exist!");
        } else {
            addGlobalInfo("Sent to {0} sockets", sent.size());
        }
    }
}
```

In here JSF page:

```
<o:socket channel="notificationChannel"
    user="#{loginBean.currentEmployee.id}" scope="view">
    <f:ajax event="someEvent" listener="#{bean.pushed}" render=":notificationLink" />
</o:socket>
```

My question is now:
How is my @EJB container recognized with Socket is the right one? Where do I define the channel name in @EJB?

Can anybody help me, please.

Comment: in Omnifaces examples are also @ViewScoped? http://showcase.omnifaces.org/push/socket

Comment: I´m not sure what you mean.... I can defined: <o:socket channel="someChannel" user="#{someLoggedInUser.id}" ... /> .... but where is "someChanel" defined in EJB container?

Comment: Do you have any example? Thank you

Comment: Code, how it looks in EJB.... Sorry, completely unclear for me

Comment: Ok, I see - you cannot or you don´t want to really help... Those short answers are not very helpful, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *How to send push via o:socket from EJB to Client?*

This title is strange as your question already shows the code which does exactly that right.

> *How is my @EJB container recognized with Socket is the right one? Where do I define the channel name in @EJB?*

This specific question is really strange in the current context. I can only assume that you actually have multiple `@Observes PushEvent` methods and that you actually wanted to target only a specific method which is associated with a specific `@Push` channel. Only in that context this question would make somewhat sense.

Well, in order to achieve that, there are several ways.

1. Pass it as an argument/property of the `PushEvent` class:

   ```
   beanManager.fireEvent(new PushEvent("notificationChannel", "Test"));
   ```

   And then just check for that in your observer method:

   ```
   if ("notificationChannel".equals(event.getChannelName())) {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   Feel free to use enums instead.

   ---
2. Or, create a specific class for every specific event:

   ```
   beanManager.fireEvent(new NotificationEvent("Test"));
   ```

   And then just make sure you observe it in only one method:

   ```
   public void pushUser(@Observes NotificationEvent event) {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   ---
3. Or, create a `@Qualifier` for the `PushEvent`:

   ```
   @Qualifier
   @Retention(RUNTIME)
   @Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER })
   public @interface Notification {}
   ```

   Which you `@Inject` via `Event<T>`:

   ```
   @Inject @Notification
   private Event<PushEvent> pushEvent;

   public void createNotification {
       pushEvent.fire(new PushEvent("Test"));
   }
   ```

   And then just make sure you observe it in only one method:

   ```
   public void pushUser(@Observes @Notification PushEvent event) {
       // ...
   }
   ```